# Android custom AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm creating a custom `AlertDialog` and I'm getting one error.

On `strings.xml` I have defined a string like:

```
<string name="infoDetail">Test: <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></string>
```

I've created a custom layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoVersionTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="right|center"
        android:text="@string/infoVersion"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoVersionTitleValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/infoVersionTitle"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoDetailText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/infoVersionTitle"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/infoDetail" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code for creating the `AlertDialog` with my custom layout:

```
case R.id.info:
    AlertDialog.Builder about = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    about.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    about.setIcon(R.drawable.info);
    about.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info, null));


    TextView infoDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoDetailText);
    infoDetail.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    about.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();                       
        }
    });
    about.show();               
    break;
```

Whit this I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on `infoDetail.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`.

If I remove this line my custom layout is shown as expected but the url is not clickable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please see below link for make custom alert dialog [Android Custom Dialog Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) [Android Custom Alert Dialog Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/)

Comment: Thanks, but that not solves my problem of clicking on the URL

Comment: The main problem in this line. TextView infoDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoDetailText);

Comment: @DipakKeshariya Yes.  You are right. But cant seem to bypass this situation. Have done `LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();View infoLayout = li.inflate(R.layout.info, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.infoLayout));` about.setView(infoLayout);about.setView(infoLayout);` and then     `AlertDialog infoDialog = about.create(); infoDialog.show();((TextView)infoDialog.findViewById(R.id.infoDetailText)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` but that does not solve my problem. Stuck at this point

Comment: your problem is solved or not?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya Not solved. Managed to show the text but the links do not work. They're not even underlined

Answer (score 0):

When using widgets in dialog should refer it with dialog name like

```
TextView nameTextView = (TextView) your_dialog_name.findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
```

or they will show null pointer exception so

refer the TextView like

```
   TextView infoDetail = (TextView) about.findViewById(R.id.infoDetailText);
```

Comment: Hi. done that but gives me an error. `The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder` and the given cast options are `Activity`, `Dialog` and `View` all of which then give `Cannot cast from AlertDialog.Builder to type`. Done this: `View infoLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info, null);` `about.setView(infoLayout);` and then     TextView infoDetail = (TextView) infoLayout.findViewById(R.id.infoDetailText);   infoDetail.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`. Now it shows but cannot click link. It also does not appear underlined in blue.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
TextView textview = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

aswell?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
about.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info, null));

TextView infoDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoDetailText);
```

with

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info, null);
about.setView(v);
TextView infoDetail = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.infoDetailText);
```

Because you will need to call `findViewById()` on the dialog's view hierarchy, not on your activity's. A view with the specified id does not exist in the activity hierarchy and a null is returned. Attempting to invoke a method (`setMovementMethod`) on null causes the NPE.

(Yeah, I know, old question but got [random-bumped as unanswered by Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) and it was easy to answer.)